# @Html.DropDownList fails to initialize value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor-3

I have a simple piece of code that tries to populate a list of 3 countries and select the 2nd item by default. For some reason, @Html.DropDownList is not initializing the 2nd item in the screen. Can someone point out whats wrong with this code ?

```
public class DemoController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Test()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> ddlCountries = new List<SelectListItem>();
        SelectListItem item1 = new SelectListItem { Selected = false, Text = "USA", Value = "1" };
        SelectListItem item2 = new SelectListItem { Selected = true, Text = "Ireland", Value = "2" };
        SelectListItem item3 = new SelectListItem { Selected = false, Text = "UK", Value = "3" };

        ddlCountries.Add(item1);
        ddlCountries.Add(item2);
        ddlCountries.Add(item3);

        ViewBag.ddlCountries = ddlCountries;
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public string Test(string ddlCountries)
    {
        return "The selected Value was " + ddlCountries;
    }
}
```

**The below is the output on the screen..**

[image: Screen Output]

**The quickwatch window shows that the "Selected" property is correctly set to value "2", yet the screen doesn't reflect this..**

[image: Quickwatch output]

The code for the view is the following

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Test";
}

<h2>Test</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Test", "Demo", FormMethod.Post))
{ 

@Html.DropDownList("ddlCountries", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>) ViewBag.ddlCountries)
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

Comment: You could try to use a `SelectList` object instead of a `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` object.

Comment: @codingstill, and how is that any different? By the way `SelectList` implements `IEnumerable<SelectListView>`.

Answer (score 6):

Try using a view model, it's much easier, safer and cleaner:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string SelectedCountryId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Countries { get; set; }
}
```

and then in your controller:

```
public class DemoController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Test()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> ddlCountries = new List<SelectListItem>();
        SelectListItem item1 = new SelectListItem { Text = "USA", Value = "1" };
        SelectListItem item2 = new SelectListItem { Text = "Ireland", Value = "2" };
        SelectListItem item3 = new SelectListItem { Text = "UK", Value = "3" };

        ddlCountries.Add(item1);
        ddlCountries.Add(item2);
        ddlCountries.Add(item3);

        var model = new MyViewModel();
        model.Countries = ddlCountries;
        model.SelectedCountryId = "2"; // preseleted Ireland

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Test(MyViewModel model)
    {
        return Content("The selected Value was " + model.SelectedCountryId);
    }
}
```

and finally in your strongly typed view:

```
@model MyViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Test";
}

<h2>Test</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Test", "Demo", FormMethod.Post))
{ 
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedCountryId, Model.Countries)
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

and that's pretty much the correct approach. Forget about any ViewBag stuff. Just use a view model. The single source of information for the view must be the view model.

By the way the GET controller action could be simplified to:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Test()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel();
    model.Countries = new[]
    {
        new SelectListItem { Text = "USA", Value = "1" },
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Ireland", Value = "2" },
        new SelectListItem { Text = "UK", Value = "3" },
    };
    model.SelectedCountryId = "2"; // preseleted Ireland

    return View(model);
}
```

or the countries could be directly bound in your view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string SelectedCountryId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Countries 
    {
        get
        {
            return new[]
            {
                new SelectListItem { Text = "USA", Value = "1" },
                new SelectListItem { Text = "Ireland", Value = "2" },
                new SelectListItem { Text = "UK", Value = "3" },
            };
        }
    }
}
```

and then your controller becomes even slimmer:

```
public class DemoController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Test()
    {
        var model = new MyViewModel();
        model.SelectedCountryId = "2"; // preseleted Ireland
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Test(MyViewModel model)
    {
        return Content("The selected Value was " + model.SelectedCountryId);
    }
}
```

Comment: @KarticKalyan, if this post helped you solve the problem you were having you might consider marking it as answer by clicking on the tick next to it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work